# Why am I getting the error "'CSS3DObject' is not exported from 'three'"?

Tags: reactjs, three.js

I wanted to implement the code from this video:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nPEYdw2Ssa8
(you can download it from here https://codepen.io/i2801/pen/waQPQj)
but using React. I had no luck and got error:

```
Attempted import error: 'CSS3DObject' is not exported from 'three' (imported as 'THREE').
```

Of course I have installed all the dependencies i tried to import

So here is My code

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import * as THREE from 'three';
import OrbitControls from 'three-orbitcontrols';
import Tween from 'three-tween';
import TrackballControls from 'three-trackballcontrols';
import CSS3DRenderer from 'three-css3drenderer';
export default class Scene extends Component {

  componentWillMount() {
    window.addEventListener('resize', this.handleWindowResize)
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.setupScene();
    this.THREE = THREE;
  }

  setupScene = () => {
    this.THREE = THREE;
    let objects = [];
    let targets = { table: [], sphere: [], helix: [], grid: [] };
    let table = [
      "H", "Hydrogen", "1.00794", 1, 1,
      //Deleted most of the stuff to save space
      "Uuo", "Ununoctium", "(294)", 18, 7
    ];

    this.width = this.container.clientWidth;
    this.height = this.container.clientHeight;

    const renderer = new THREE.CSS3DRenderer();
    renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
    renderer.domElement.style.position = 'absolute';
    document.getElementById('container').appendChild(renderer.domElement);

    let scene = new THREE.Scene();

    const camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(40, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1, 10000);
    camera.position.z = 3000;
    scene.add(camera);

    this.renderer = renderer;
    this.scene = scene;
    this.camera = camera;
    this.objects = objects;
    this.targets = targets;

    for (var i = 0; i < table.length; i += 5) {

      var element = document.createElement('div');
      element.className = 'element';
      element.style.backgroundColor = 'rgba(0,127,127,' + (Math.random() * 0.5 + 0.25) + ')';

      var number = document.createElement('div');
      number.className = 'number';
      number.textContent = (i / 5) + 1;
      element.appendChild(number);

      var symbol = document.createElement('div');
      symbol.className = 'symbol';
      symbol.textContent = table[i];
      element.appendChild(symbol);

      var details = document.createElement('div');
      details.className = 'details';
      details.innerHTML = table[i + 1] + '<br>' + table[i + 2];
      element.appendChild(details);
      var object = new THREE.CSS3DObject(element);
      object.position.x = Math.random() * 4000 - 2000;
      object.position.y = Math.random() * 4000 - 2000;
      object.position.z = Math.random() * 4000 - 2000;
      scene.add(object);

      objects.push(object);

      var object = new THREE.Object3D();
      object.position.x = (table[i + 3] * 140) - 1260;
      object.position.y = - (table[i + 4] * 180) + 990;

      targets.table.push(object);
    }
    for (var i = 0; i < objects.length; i++) {

      var object = new THREE.Object3D();

      object.position.x = ((i % 5) * 400) - 800;
      object.position.y = (- (Math.floor(i / 5) % 5) * 400) + 800;
      object.position.z = (Math.floor(i / 25)) * 1000 - 2000;

      targets.grid.push(object);

    }

    //

    this.renderer = new THREE.CSS3DRenderer();
    this.renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
    this.renderer.domElement.style.position = 'absolute';
    document.getElementById('container').appendChild(renderer.domElement);

    //

    this.controls = new THREE.TrackballControls(camera, renderer.domElement);
    this.controls.rotateSpeed = 0.5;
    this.controls.minDistance = 500;
    this.controls.maxDistance = 6000;
    this.controls.addEventListener('change', this.renderScene);

    var button = document.getElementById('table');
    button.addEventListener('click', event => {

      this.transform(targets.table, 2000);

    }, false);

    // var button = document.getElementById('sphere');
    // button.addEventListener('click', event => {

    //   transform(targets.sphere, 2000);

    // }, false);

    // var button = document.getElementById('helix');
    // button.addEventListener('click', event => {

    //   transform(targets.helix, 2000);

    // }, false);

    // var button = document.getElementById('grid');
    // button.addEventListener('click', event => {

    //   transform(targets.grid, 2000);

    // }, false);

    this.transform(targets.table, 2000);

    //

    this.start();
  }
  transform = (targets, duration) => {

    TWEEN.removeAll();

    for (var i = 0; i < objects.length; i++) {

      var object = this.objects[i];
      var target = this.targets[i];

      new TWEEN.Tween(object.position)
        .to({ x: target.position.x, y: target.position.y, z: target.position.z }, Math.random() * duration + duration)
        .easing(TWEEN.Easing.Exponential.InOut)
        .start();

      new TWEEN.Tween(object.rotation)
        .to({ x: target.rotation.x, y: target.rotation.y, z: target.rotation.z }, Math.random() * duration + duration)
        .easing(TWEEN.Easing.Exponential.InOut)
        .start();

    }

    new TWEEN.Tween(this)
      .to({}, duration * 2)
      .onUpdate(this.renderScene)
      .start();

  }

  start = () => {
    if (!this.frameId) {
      this.frameId = requestAnimationFrame(this.animate)
    }
  }

  renderScene = () => {
    this.renderer.render(this.scene, this.camera)
  }

  animate = () => {
    this.frameId = requestAnimationFrame(this.animate);
    this.renderScene();
    TWEEN.update();
    this.controls.update();
  }

  stop = () => {
    cancelAnimationFrame(this.frameId);
  }

  handleWindowResize = () => {
    this.camera.aspect = window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight;
    this.camera.updateProjectionMatrix();

    this.renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);

    this.renderScene();
  }

  componentWillUnmount = () => {
    this.stop();
    this.destroyContext();
  }

  destroyContext = () => {
    this.container.removeChild(this.renderer.domElement);
    this.renderer.forceContextLoss();
    this.renderer.context = null;
    this.renderer.domElement = null;
    this.renderer = null;
  }


  render() {
    const width = '100%';
    const height = '100%';
    return (
      <div
        ref={(container) => { this.container = container }}
        style={{ width: width, height: height, position: 'absolute', overflow: 'hidden' }}
      >
      </div>
    )
  }

}
```

Thanks in advance,
Stack is complaining about my post being mostly code so here is some dummy text to bypass it: Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aliquam sodales volutpat ligula, sed iaculis metus consectetur eget. Sed vulputate tellus vel velit consequat scelerisque. Vestibulum sodales massa risus, ac

Comment: The error message suggests that this line `const renderer = new THREE.CSS3DRenderer();` is causing a problem since `CSS3DRenderer` in not inside `THREE`.
https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/issues/7309

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`THREE.CSS3DObject` is not part of the `three.js` core. But you should be able to import it from the `npm` module `three-css3drenderer`. Try this:

```
import { CSS3DObject } from 'three-css3drenderer';
```

Also ensure to create you renderer like so (notice the missing `THREE` namespace):

```
this.renderer = new CSS3DRenderer();
```

Comment: I did what you said and now i have this error `TypeError: three_css3drenderer__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_11___default.a is not a constructor`

Comment: Can you try the import like so: `import { CSS3DObject } from 'three-css3drenderer';`. Same for `CSS3DRenderer`.

Answer (score 1):

With help of Mugen87 i have got every thing set up and working !
If you would like to try this on your own here is the code you need :

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import * as THREE from 'three';
import OrbitControls from 'three-orbitcontrols/OrbitControls';
import TWEEN from 'three-tween';
import TrackballControls from 'three-trackballcontrols';
import { CSS3DRenderer } from 'three-css3drenderer';
import { CSS3DObject } from 'three-css3drenderer';

export default class Scene extends Component {

  componentWillMount() {
    window.addEventListener('resize', this.handleWindowResize)
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.setupScene();
    this.THREE = THREE;
  }

  setupScene = () => {
    this.THREE = THREE;
    this.objects = [];
    this.targets = { table: [], sphere: [], helix: [], grid: [] };
    this.table = [
      "H", "Hydrogen", "1.00794", 1, 1,
      //Deleted most of the stuff to save up space
      "Uuo", "Ununoctium", "(294)", 18, 7
    ];

    this.width = this.container.clientWidth;
    this.height = this.container.clientHeight;

    this.renderer = new CSS3DRenderer();
    this.renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
    this.renderer.domElement.style.position = 'absolute';
    document.getElementById('container').appendChild(this.renderer.domElement);

    this.scene = new THREE.Scene();

    this.camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(40, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1, 10000);
    this.camera.position.z = 3000;
    this.scene.add(this.camera);




    for (var i = 0; i < this.table.length; i += 5) {

      var element = document.createElement('div');
      element.className = 'element';
      element.style.backgroundColor = 'rgba(0,127,127,' + (Math.random() * 0.5 + 0.25) + ')';

      var number = document.createElement('div');
      number.className = 'number';
      number.textContent = (i / 5) + 1;
      element.appendChild(number);

      var symbol = document.createElement('div');
      symbol.className = 'symbol';
      symbol.textContent = this.table[i];
      element.appendChild(symbol);

      var details = document.createElement('div');
      details.className = 'details';
      details.innerHTML = this.table[i + 1] + '<br>' + this.table[i + 2];
      element.appendChild(details);
      var object = new CSS3DObject(element);
      object.position.x = Math.random() * 4000 - 2000;
      object.position.y = Math.random() * 4000 - 2000;
      object.position.z = Math.random() * 4000 - 2000;
      this.scene.add(object);

      this.objects.push(object);

      var object = new THREE.Object3D();
      object.position.x = (this.table[i + 3] * 140) - 1260;
      object.position.y = - (this.table[i + 4] * 180) + 990;

      this.targets.table.push(object);
    }
    for (var i = 0; i < this.objects.length; i++) {

      var object = new THREE.Object3D();

      object.position.x = ((i % 5) * 400) - 800;
      object.position.y = (- (Math.floor(i / 5) % 5) * 400) + 800;
      object.position.z = (Math.floor(i / 25)) * 1000 - 2000;

      this.targets.grid.push(object);

    }


    this.controls = new TrackballControls(this.camera, this.renderer.domElement);
    this.controls.rotateSpeed = 0.5;
    this.controls.minDistance = 500;
    this.controls.maxDistance = 6000;
    this.controls.addEventListener('change', this.renderScene);

    // var button = document.getElementById('table');
    // button.addEventListener('click', event => {

    //   this.transform(this.targets.table, 2000);

    // }, false);

    // var button = document.getElementById('sphere');
    // button.addEventListener('click', event => {

    //   transform(targets.sphere, 2000);

    // }, false);

    // var button = document.getElementById('helix');
    // button.addEventListener('click', event => {

    //   transform(targets.helix, 2000);

    // }, false);

    // var button = document.getElementById('grid');
    // button.addEventListener('click', event => {

    //   transform(targets.grid, 2000);

    // }, false);

    this.transform(this.targets.table, 2000);

    //

    this.start();
  }
  transform = (targets, duration) => {

    TWEEN.removeAll();

    for (var i = 0; i < this.objects.length; i++) {

      var object = this.objects[i];
      var target = targets[i];

      new TWEEN.Tween(object.position)
        .to({ x: target.position.x, y: target.position.y, z: target.position.z }, Math.random() * duration + duration)
        .easing(TWEEN.Easing.Exponential.InOut)
        .start();

      new TWEEN.Tween(object.rotation)
        .to({ x: target.rotation.x, y: target.rotation.y, z: target.rotation.z }, Math.random() * duration + duration)
        .easing(TWEEN.Easing.Exponential.InOut)
        .start();

    }

    new TWEEN.Tween(this)
      .to({}, duration * 2)
      .onUpdate(this.renderScene)
      .start();

  }

  start = () => {
    if (!this.frameId) {
      this.frameId = requestAnimationFrame(this.animate)
    }
  }

  renderScene = () => {
    this.renderer.render(this.scene, this.camera)
  }

  animate = () => {
    this.frameId = requestAnimationFrame(this.animate);
    this.renderScene();
    TWEEN.update();
    this.controls.update();
  }

  stop = () => {
    cancelAnimationFrame(this.frameId);
  }

  handleWindowResize = () => {
    this.camera.aspect = window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight;
    this.camera.updateProjectionMatrix();

    this.renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);

    this.renderScene();
  }

  componentWillUnmount = () => {
    this.stop();
    this.destroyContext();
  }

  destroyContext = () => {
    this.container.removeChild(this.renderer.domElement);
    this.renderer.forceContextLoss();
    this.renderer.context = null;
    this.renderer.domElement = null;
    this.renderer = null;
  }


  render() {
    const width = '100%';
    const height = '100%';
    return (
      <React.Fragment>
        <div
          ref={(container) => { this.container = container }}
          style={{ width: width, height: height, position: 'absolute', overflow: 'hidden' }}
        >
        </div>
        <div id="container"></div>
      </React.Fragment>
    )
  }

}
```

Comment: Why this view-source:https://stemkoski.github.io/Three.js/CSS3D.html has two instances of `new THREE.Scene()`, one for `scene` and one for `cssScene`?